# Hpple implementation/Unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, parsing, html-parsing

I am working with the hpple html parser here: https://github.com/topfunky/hpple

To test the function I've added it to a simple project and am able to compile and open the simulator without errors, but when it is called, I get an unrecognized selector error.

```
//THIS ACTION SET TO RUN WITH THE PUSH OF A BUTTON

- (IBAction)parseElements{

NSString *urlRequest = item.link;

NSLog(@"urlRequest defined.");

NSData *htmlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlRequest] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"htmlData created.");

TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];

NSLog(@"xpathParser made.");

NSString *queriedItem = @"[@class='title']";

// THE APP FAILS WHILE TRYING TO EXECUTE THE NEXT LINE

NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:queriedItem];

NSLog(@"elements searched.");

TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"element recalled.");

NSString *storyTitle = [element content];

NSLog(@"The title of the story is: %@", storyTitle);

}
```

The NSLogs manage to display through "xpathParser made" and then I receive this unrecognized selector message:

> -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a52d60
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a52d60'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x16c8052 0x1859d0a 0x16c9ced 0x162ef00 0x162ece2 0x495c 0x352e 0x2e3f 0x16c9ec9 0x1395c2 0x13955a 0x1deb76 0x1df03f 0x1de2fe 0x15ea30 0x15ec56 0x145384 0x138aa9 0x15b2fa9 0x169c1c5 0x1601022 0x15ff90a 0x15fedb4 0x15feccb 0x15b1879 0x15b193e 0x136a9b 0x2658 0x25b5)
>   terminate called throwing an exception

I understand it doesn't like SOMETHING, but what is causing the glitch or are additional frameworks/imports necessary for proper execution? As it stands I have UIKit, viewcontroller.h and TFHpple.h set as the only imports in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
NSData *htmlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlRequest] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
```

`TFHpple`'s `initWithHTMLData` is supposed to take an `NSData`. You declare `htmlData` to be an `NSData`, but the actual object you're assigning to it is an `NSString`.

This should fix it:

```
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlRequest]];
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I crash in a different area... and the brain puzzle continues. Appreciate the explanation and I'll be sure to remember to use NSData next time.

Comment: My pleasure. The rest of the code you pasted above looks fine. Also, the line I suggested you fix should have been throwing a warning. It's always a good idea to fix all those, especially if your program is crashing. 

P.S. Feel free to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark :)