# Parsing HTML code of a page, contained in an JSON key-value pair with TFHpple in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, html-parsing, tfhpple

I'm making a native iOS app of my team's project using it's API. API has three main methods: to get user's profile information, his diary and certificate table. Last method returns to me JSON data with HTML code of a table. It looks like this

`{"html":"<table class=\"table term-marks\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellspadding=\"0\"> <thead> <tr> <td>\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043c\u0435\u0442<\/td> <td colspan=\"10\">\u041e\u0446\u0435\u043d\u043a\u0438<\/td><td width=\"60px\">\u0421\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043d\u0438\u0439 <br\/>\u0431\u0430\u043b\u043b<\/td> <td width=\"60px\">\u0421\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043d\u0438\u0439 <br\/>\u043f\u043e \u043a\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0443<\/td> <td width=\"60px\">\u0421\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043d\u0438\u0439 <br\/>\u043f\u043e \u043f\u0430\u0440\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0435\u043b\u0438<\/td><td width=\"60px\">\u0418\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0446\u0435\u043d\u043a\u0430<\/td> <\/tr> <\/thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>\u0410\u043d\u0433\u043b\u0438\u0439\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.60<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0411\u0438\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u044f<\/td> <td>3<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.50<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0413\u0435\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u044f<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>3<\/td> <td>2<\/td> <td>3<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>3.40<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0418\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0438 \u0418\u041a\u0422<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.75<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0418\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0441\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0418\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>2<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>3.50<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u041b\u0438\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.00<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u041c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u043a\u0430<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>3<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>2<\/td> <td>3<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4.00<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u041e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\u0437\u043d\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.00<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0420\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u044f\u0437\u044b\u043a<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.80<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0422\u0430\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043b\u0438\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0422\u0430\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u044f\u0437\u044b\u043a<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.00<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0424\u0438\u0437\u0438\u043a\u0430<\/td> <td>3<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.00<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0424\u0438\u0437\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043a\u0443\u043b\u044c\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.50<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr> <td>\u0425\u0438\u043c\u0438\u044f<\/td> <td>4<\/td> <td>5<\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td>4.50<\/td><td><\/td> <td><\/td> <td><\/td> <\/tr> <tr><td colspan=\"11\"><strong>\u0418\u0422\u041e\u0413\u041e<\/strong><\/td><td>3.88<\/td> <td>0<\/td> <td>0<\/td> <td>-<\/td><\/tr> <\/tbody> <\/table>"}`

I've tried to create an NSDictionary with this JSON data and get NSData from there like this:

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSData alloc] init];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil]; // responseData contains API response
htmlData = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"html"];
TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *tableRows = [mainParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//tr/td"]
```

But I'm getting the same error like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810926/hpple-implementation-unrecognized-selector). But I can't use the solution from there, because I don't have an URL to the table, I only have it's html code. How can I parse it?

Comment: There is no need to alloc/init htmlData; You are just waisting CPU there. That is not your problem, of course.

Comment: @HermannKlecker thanks for an advise! I'm just 16 years old and I'm a beginner to Obj-C programming :) Will try your solution now.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving an `NSString` object from `[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"html"];`

Regardless how you actually declared the receiving variable, `NSData` in this case, it will be assigned what the method actually returns. And that is an `NSString` in this case.

In general it is advisable to receive the data in a variable of type id first and then check its class using `isKindOfClass` and then go from there.

```
NSData *htmlData;
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
id nextElement = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"html"];
if (id isKindOfClass:[NSString class]) {
  htmlData = [(NSString*)id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} else {
   // Deal with the error or cover other classes accordingly 
} 
TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *tableRows = [mainParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//tr/td"]
```